# cakephp login redirect problem?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Hi I'm using cakephp auth component for login system, I would like,every time when user login to redirect him to users page,but when session is timeout and user login again he is redirected to previous page that he was on,and not back to users page.I hope you understand me.He is my code.

app controller :

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('admin' => false, 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');

    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('admin' => false, 'controller' => 'books', 'action' => 'index');

    $this->Auth->allow('display');
}
```

users controller :

```
function login() {
            }

    function admin_logout() {
        $this->Session->destroy(); 
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());

    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to redirect the user out of the page he was on? If he was doing something on your site and his session times out and is refreshed it's a better user experience if he picks up where he left off

Comment: I know,it doesn't make sense,but I want to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in beforeFilter in users controller, add `$this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;` and

> ```
> function login() {
>     if($this->Auth->user())$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'books', 'action' => 'index'));
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a tricky one, because I think the Session component will not let you do what it is you want unless you modify it, what you can do is open config/core.php in your app and modify your Security.level and Session.timeout variables to be longer, the security level works as a multiplier for the timeout variable if it's high the multiplier is 10, 100 if it's medium and 300 if it's low

Comment: Hi,thank you for response.I don't know how will changing security level help me,but I will try.

Comment: You can extend the time so the session doesn't expire so fast, because doing what you want isn't very trivial because you have to modify the way Cake handles sessions

Comment: Yes,I know that,issue was just to redirect on homepage when session is timeout